# How to identify if a control/plugin was triggered from a custom button on the ribbon in CRM 2011?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

I am basically trying to find out how to identify if anything (any control, plugin or workflow) was triggered from a custom button on the ribbon of an entity. Is there a way to identify it?

One way is I change a boolean field on the form on click of the custom button. Is there any other better or efficient solution?

I am using CRM 2011 and triggering a custom plugin on the update of the entity.

Thank in advance.

kva888

Comment: The only way I know to identify if a plugin has been triggered is to add Trace in it.

Answer (score 3):

*[Original answer removed]*

*Apologies - I posted in haste. Have re-read your question and realise you are proposing the same solution and wondering if there are alternatives...*

---

In short, there is no footprint available server-side that tells you anything about what client-side method was used to change an attribute.

The solution you describe (set a flag whenever the ribbon button changes something) is, I'm certain, the only option.